# Display tag external sort with 'sortName' property returns null in controller

Tags: java, jsp, sorting, displaytag

I have been trying to implement displaytag external sort with 'sortName' property but for some reason in controller the sorted column name is turning up 'null'. I tired various things but none works. I need help on this.

Here's the jsp code

```
        <display-el:table sort="external" id="dispTable" defaultsort="1" name="displayItems" 
            class="default" style="width:100%" export="false" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" pagesize="${itemPerPage}"
            partialList="true" size="resultSize" decorator="MeiSummaryRecordDecorator" requestURI="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/meireports/${requestScope.requestURI}">
            <display-el:column property="displayCrid" sortable="true" sortName="s.edoc_crid" title="Responsible CRID" class="defaultTextCentered" style="text-align:center; width:2%;" sortProperty="displayCrid"/>
            <display-el:column property="displayInvoiceDate" sortable="true" sortName="invoice_period" title="Invoice Period" class="defaultTextCentered" style="width:2%;" sortProperty="invoiceDate"/>
```

Here's the controller code

```
    ParamEncoder encoder = new ParamEncoder("dispTable");
    String sortBy = request.getParameter(encoder.encodeParameterName(TableTagParameters.PARAMETER_SORT));
```

Note that in controller I also tried which didnt work either

```
    ParamEncoder encoder = new ParamEncoder("dispTable");
    String sortBy = request.getParameter(encoder.encodeParameterName(TableTagParameters.PARAMETER_SORTUSINGNAME));
```

I do see the encoded value of the parameter but when I do request.getParameter I get null value. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I noticed on sortable column that the href doesnt have the encoded value appended to the url

Comment: I would really appreciate some help here. Thanks!!

Comment: did you ever solve this?